# mod_rewrite - how to make two rules work together

Tags: mod-rewrite, combinations

I've been trying to make friendly urls for my site and have the following rules:

```
#enable rewrites
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Redirect 404s
ErrorDocument 404 /404_not_found.cfm

# Redirect non www to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.co.uk/$1 [L,R=301]

# Add trailing slashes to uri 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(images|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L,NC]

# Redirect any request with page var to /var/ format

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(.+[^/])$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.cfm$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/ [R=301,L,NC]

# If not an existing file or directory
# Rewrite any request var/ to index.cfm?page=var

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ /index.cfm?page=$1 [QSA,L]

# property services

# Add trailing slash if not a file or directory and 301 redirect
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^property-services/([^/.]+)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/property-services/$1/ [R=301,L,NC]

# Rewrite request any request with page var to property-services/var/
RewriteRule ^property-services/([^/.]+)/$ property-services/index.cfm?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Everything works accept the final rule:

```
# Rewrite request any request with page var to property-services/var/
RewriteRule ^property-services/([^/.]+)/$ property-services/index.cfm?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

The page isn't being loaded when I try to request:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/property-services/example-service/
```

If I remove the second to last and rule then I can get the page to load by requesting:

```
http://www.example.co.uk/property-services/example-service
```

The point is I need to load the page with the slash on the end as this is the format I have chosen for the site. Could someone explain where I am wrong please?

Comment: Just for simplicity: You can pack most of `RewriteCond` together: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d RewriteRule .* - [l]`

Comment: Thanks for the advice KingCrunch, is that a global rule so I don't have to keep using RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d for each rule?

Comment: Its the negation of what you are doing now: You say "if X is not file and not directory do Y" (4 times). I say "If x is file or directory, do nothing", so you should only need it once. `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR] RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d RewriteRule .* - [L]` (I forgot the `[OR]`-flag ;)). It should make it more readable, but I'm not completely sure, that it doesn't interfere with other rules/conds.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks for the explanation. I will add that in. Do you have any suggestions for my main problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rule will match any URL which ends with a single slash, (but not a double slash), so it will prevent your last rule from being reached.

```
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])/$ /index.cfm?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I suspect you were needing something along the lines of:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /index.cfm?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks mootinator, that's helped me find the solution i was after.